# Should reliability test (cronbach alpha) include missing values?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, spss, missing-data, cronbachs-alpha

I am currently doing a reliability test for my questionnaires with 34 respondents. However, there are some missing values in the questionnaires which I'm not sure whether I need to include or exclude them from the reliability test.

I had define my missing value as 0 and 9 for monthly allowance and CGPA part respectively. But it seems like the SPSS will automatically delete listwise the missing values. And my Cronbach alpha results seems really weird.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your alpha is weird because you're throwing together a bunch of variables that don't go together.

You should use alpha when you have a set of items that measure a similar construct - e.g. a set of math questions, or a set of questions that ask about a person's depression symptoms.

Usually, these items should be measured on a similar scale.